# How to check for this validation with Yup

Tags: reactjs, yup

```
[{id: 1, name: "", surname:""},{id: 2, name: "", surname:""}] false
```

[{id: 1, name: "John", surname:"Doe"},{id: 2, name: "", surname:""}] true
[{id: 1, name: "John", surname:"Doe"},{id: 2, name: "John", surname:"Wick"] true

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and what problem you encountered with your solution.

Comment: I made name input according to languages. for example: if there is two language named English and French. there will be two input for each language. user must fill one input of existed languages. other languages is filled or not. no problem.